# $\sum (\frac{1-2n}{6+2n})^n $ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Verify if

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-2n}{6+2n}\right)^n $$

converges

The root test is inconclusive and the limit of the general term is 0. I think I should use the comparison test, in this case. But I couldnt find any functiob to use. Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say the limit of the general term is 0?

Comment: the root test shows the limit is $-1$, meaning that since it is $< 1$, the series should converge.

Comment: @VarunIyer By that logic, $\sum_n (-2)^n$ should converge!

Comment: The root test says we should use $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|}$. For large $n$, the numerator of $\sqrt[n]{|x_n|}$ is $2n - 1$, so the limit is $1$ and the test fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_n=\left(\dfrac{1-2n}{6+2n}\right)^n$. We have that
$$|a_n|=\left|\dfrac{2n-1}{6+2n}\right|^n=\exp\left[n \log \left(\dfrac{2n-1}{6+2n}\right)\right].$$
Let $b_n=n \log \left(\dfrac{2n-1}{6+2n}\right)$. Making the substitution $n=\dfrac{1}{x}$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}\log\left(\dfrac{2-x}{2+6x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}\log\left(1-\dfrac{7x}{2+6x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}\left(-\dfrac{7x}{2+6x}\right)=-\dfrac{7}{2}.$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|=\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{b_n}=e^{-\tfrac{7}{2}},$$
and the series diverges by the divergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Ive find out that L'Hospital also works.

Answer (score 2):

(Expanding my comment into an answer)

Here's a broad hint: $\left(\dfrac{1-2n}{6+2n}\right) = -\left(\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+6}\right) = -\left(1-\dfrac{7}{2n+6}\right)$, so your general term is $(-1)^n\left(1-\dfrac{7}{2n+6}\right)^n$.  Now, set $y=2n+6$ (so $n=\frac12(y-6)=\frac12y-3$); then the positive piece of this term (setting aside the $(-1)^n$ for the moment) is $\left(1-\frac{7}{y}\right)^{\frac12y-3} = \left(1-\frac7y\right)^{-3}\cdot\left(\left(1-\frac7y\right)^y\right)^{\frac12}$.  The inner portion of the right hand side of this expression should look a little familiar...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{2n-1}{2n+6}\bigg)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}}{1+\frac{3}{n}}\bigg)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{n})^n}{(1+\frac{3}{n})^n}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^3}=e^{-\frac{7}{2}}\ne0$,

so the series diverges.